# Oracle (SQL Statements) - Using CASE with WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: sql, oracle, case, where-clause

*Dear Experts,
I preparing an SQL report to display the data with Format_Check validations using CASE. I have provided the example,issues and expectation below:*

**Table Structure:**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XIRH.png)

**SQL Statement:**

```
SELECT 

ID,PRODUCT,COMMENTS

CASE WHEN SUBSTR(COMMENTS,1,35)=REGEXP_SUBSTR (COMMENTS,'(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\s)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\s)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\s)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)',1,1)
AND
LENGTH(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR (COMMENTS, '(\S*)(\s)', 1, 2)))=8 
AND
REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR (COMMENTS, '(\S*)(\s)', 1, 1)),'(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)')
THEN 'Correct Format'
ELSE 'Incorrect_Format'
END AS Format_Check

FROM TEST_TABLE
```

**SQL Output:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkn65.png)

**SQL Output Explanation:**

> 1. Checks whether COMMENTS column is 35 Character long, also checks the format numbers and spaces. SUBSTR(COMMENTS,1,35)=REGEXP_SUBSTR
>      (COMMENTS,'(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\s)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\s)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\s)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)',1,1)
> 2. Checks whether the comments after first space is 8 characters long LENGTH(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR (COMMENTS, '(\S*)(\s)', 1, 2)))=8
> 3. Checks the first 8 characters is digit/number. REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR (COMMENTS, '(\S*)(\s)', 1,
>      1)),'(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)')

**Expectation:**

*I need only the 'Incorrect Format' comments to be displayed when the SQL is executed, I don't wish to see the 'Correct Format' comments. However I need your advise on whether this case be used with WHERE clause to display only incorrect format COMMENTS alone.
I referred previous queries related to WHERE and CASE, however I can't figure out on how pass my case in WHERE clause.
Thanks for your help.*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the incorrect format columns, you can wrap your query with another one:

```
SELECT id, product, comment, format_check
  FROM (
        SELECT id, product, comment, CASE WHEN .... END AS format_check
          FROM test_table
       )
 WHERE format_check = 'Incorrect_Format';
```

BTW, your question is easier to answer if you show your table and data with SQL instead of an image, for instance like:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (id NUMBER, product VARCHAR2(10), comments VARCHAR2(50));
INSERT INTO  test_table VALUES (1,'Laptop', '00000001 01012020 02022020 03032020');
INSERT INTO  test_table VALUES (1,'PC',     '   00000001 01012020 02022020 0034');
```

Furthermore, I believe the regular expression can be simplified. Please provide a bit more detail if you're interested...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to see the correct format in the result at all then you can omit the calculation of the format in `select` clause. Rather use it in `Where` clause as follows:

```
SELECT ID,
       PRODUCT,
       COMMENTS,
      'Incorrect_Format' AS format_check
  FROM TEST_TABLE
 WHERE CASE WHEN SUBSTR(COMMENTS,1,35)=REGEXP_SUBSTR (COMMENTS,'(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\s)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\s)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\s)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)',1,1)
AND
LENGTH(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR (COMMENTS, '(\S*)(\s)', 1, 2)))=8 
AND
REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR (COMMENTS, '(\S*)(\s)', 1, 1)),'(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)')
THEN 'Correct Format'
ELSE 'Incorrect_Format'
END AS = 'Incorrect_Format'
```